# innerHTML in Combination with parseFloat

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What I'm attempting to do can be accomplished by the following...

```
elementContent = document.getElementById('docElement').innerHTML;
elementContent = parseFloat(elementContent);
```

or even by...

```
elementContent = parseFloat( document.getElementById('docElement').innerHTML );
```

but I can't help to wonder if there's a more elegant way to retrieve and assign DOM content as a float that I may be unaware of. Any insight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the [unary plus operator](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/unary-add/) which tries to convert a string (or another type's `toString()`) to a number.  It would be used like:

```
elementContent = +document.getElementById('docElement').innerHTML;
```

As others have mentioned you can use jQuery as essentially syntactic sugar for .innerHTML here, also.

Comment: +1 and Answered! This is exactly the sort of "something I may be unaware of" that I was hoping for. Thanks a ton for chiming in!

Answer (score 3):

That's a fine way to go about doing things. The only thing I could suggest would be that if you can avoid working with the HTML markup entirely, by storing the "clean" number as an attribute of the element, that would be preferable, as it would get around problems that might be introduced if the HTML gets fancier than you expect it to be. (For example, sometimes designers want negative numbers formatted with the Unicode "minus" glyph instead of the plain hyphen, because it looks better.)

Thus if you could generate your elements like this:

```
<span id='docElement' data-value='29.20221'>29.20221</span>
```

then instead of accessing the value as ".innerHTML" you'd use ".getAttribute()":

```
var value = document.getElementById('docElement').getAttribute('data-value');
value = parseFloat(value);
```

Comment: I've always been a little uneasy assigning new attributes to elements because they often piss the w3c validator off, but you actually do bring up a great point. The data I'm pulling is a price and I'd otherwise have to `substr` if I wanted to use a dollar sign.

Comment: If you use the HTML5 doctype, then all "data-foo" attributes should validate (as they're explicitly part of the spec).

Comment: Good to know. I haven't exactly dove into v5 and its changes yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery:

```
var html = parseFloat($('#docElement').html());
$('#docElement').html(html);
```

Comment: The "jquery" tag doesn't appear in the original question.

Comment: @Pointy, I know, but he also put in his question this quote "if there's a more elegant way to retrieve and assign DOM content as a float that I may be unaware of", he might be "unaware" of JQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you use a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com) the code for this would be more elegant, like so:

```
var el = parseFloat( $('#docElement').text() );
```

Don't forget you might run into an issue where you need to `trim()` the string as well.